# programmatically Lock Device when call state is = ringing

Tags: java, android

how do I lock the device when there is an incoming call or sms?
I know have to ask for the user to enable device admin.
i have looked at other simialar questions on stack overflow but they all work fromt an activity and require it to be in the foreground
 My app is primarily a service it works in the background even when app is in the background. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me get this right - if the phone rings, or receives an SMS you want the phone to lock ? That doesn't sound very user friendly to me

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for commenting. Yes you are correct. That is exactly what I am trying to do. Dont worry Richard as the situation I am creating the app for is so that the user would not be distracted by phone calls or sms. Would you be able to help me ?